# Replace some words in HTML and change background with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'll make some kind of filtr: replace some bad words and change background color with using JavaScript. I have this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').html(function(i, v) {
        return v.replace(/brzydkie/g, 'CENZURA');  
    });
});
```

but i don't know how to change background color there where I changed the bad words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check <kbd>[**demo jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GHQU6/1/)</kbd>

#### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').html(function(i, v) {
        return v.replace(/brzydkie/g, '<span style="background-color:yellow;">CENZURA</span>');  
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, just target with css() function

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').html(function(i, v) {
        $('body').css("background", "#eee"); 
        return v.replace(/brzydkie/g, 'CENZURA');  
    });
});
```

**Edit 1:**

In this case, you don't have to change background through Javascript, but first you add a class in stylesheet, eg.

```
.hightlight{
   background: #f00;
}
```

And then you add a span to the words with that class, the word will have a background automatically.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').html(function(i, v) {
        return v.replace(/brzydkie/g, '<span class="highlight">CENZURA</span>');  
    });
});
```

Comment: but I'll change background only there where I change the bad words.

Comment: I have added a solution to meet your needs in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simply

```
document.body.style.background = COLOR_HERE;
```

Comment: but I'll change background only there where I change the bad words

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').html(function(i, v) {
        return v.replace(/brzydkie/g, 'CENZURA');  
    });
    $('body').css('background','#ff0000')
});
```

Here you can see it working: http://jsfiddle.net/bKKu3/

Comment: but I'll change background only there where I change the bad words.

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

```
.badwords { background-color:yellow; }
```

**JS**

```
  var badwords='<span class="badwords">CENZURA</span>';
   $('body').html(function(i, v) {
        return v.replace(/brzydkie/g, badwords);  
    });
```

I think is what you are meaning .. ( ?) - to change the background colour of the text you have replaced ?